# Flutter Cloud Firestore isLessThan Filter not Working with two .where() Statements

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm displaying a list of documents in a Cloud Firestore collection using a `StreamBuilder`. Currently, I'm able to use a `.where()` statement to filter this list of documents by title (a string), but I want to add another `.where()` statement to filter by price (a number). I want the app to only display a list of documents that have titles equal to a certain string and have prices less than a certain number. The filtering by titles works fine, but the issue is with the `isLessThan` operator when adding the second `.where()` statement.

Current code (one `.where()` statement):

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection("ads")
                  .where('title', isEqualTo: "Car")
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Text(
                      "Loading...");
                } else {
                  return //Rest of the code isn't relevant
                }
              },
            ),
```

The code I want to work with two `.where()` statements (it just returns the loading text, meaning the snapshot doesn't have any data):

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection("ads")
                  .where('title', isEqualTo: "Car")
                  .where('price', isLessThan: 12000.0) //This line is new
                  .snapshots(),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return Text(
                      "Loading...");
                } else {
                  return //Rest of the code isn't relevant
                }
              },
            ),
```

I can't decide if this is an issue with the fact that there are two `.where()` statements or if it's an issue with the `isLessThan` operator. Removing the first `.where()` statement (the one about titles) and keeping the second one about prices filters the documents by price correctly (theoretically making the issue the fact that there are 2 `.where()` statements). However, changing the `isLessThan` in the second `.where()` statement to `isEqualTo` and then changing the `12000.0` to a price I know exists in the list of documents (while keeping the first `.where()` statement) works. This makes me think that it's an issue with combining the `isLessThan` operator and a second `.where()` statement.

Note: all price values in the Firestore collection are doubles (the data type in Cloud Firestore is set to "number" and they all have decimals - e.g. 1.0 instead of 1).

Comment: Did you define an index for the combination of fields you are querying? If not, check the log output of your app for a message about a missing index - and a link to create it.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm not exactly sure what you mean by an index, but there's nothing about a missing index in the log output. The log output is empty!